# How can I verify 2 different TR ID numbers with JS on the same HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page and 2 different TR Identity Numbers are entered into the form in it. I want to check the accuracy of these 2 TR ID numbers with Javascript. I can only control 1 of them with the current javascript. MY Page is below.

```
               <p>
                        <label for="id_identity_bride">TC Kimlik/Pasaport No:</label> 
                        <input type="text" name="identity_bride" size="24" class="input" placeholder="Gelin TC Kimlik/Pasaport No" maxlength="11" required id="id_identity_bride" >
                        
                        <input type="text" name="identity_groom" size="25" class="input" placeholder="Damat TC Kimlik/Pasaport No" maxlength="11" required id="id_identity_groom">
                        <div id="sonuc"></div>
                    </p>

                    
                    <script>
                        /*Gelin - TC Kimlik Kontrol*/
                        var TCKimlikKOntrol = function(deger) {
                        deger = deger.toString();
                        var basamak = /^[0-9]{11}$/.test(deger);
                        var toplamX = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                            toplamX += Number(deger.substr(i, 1));
                        }
                        var kuralX = toplamX % 10 == deger.substr(10,1);
                        var toplamY = 0;
                        var toplamY = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i+=2) {
                            toplamY += Number(deger.substr(i, 1));
                        }
                        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i+=2) {
                            toplamY += Number(deger.substr(i, 1));
                        }
                        var kuralY = ((toplamY * 7) - toplamY) % 10 == deger.substr(9,0);
                        return basamak && kuralX && kuralY;
                        };
                        /*TC Kimlik Kontrol*/
                    
                        const inputTCNO=document.querySelector("#id_identity_bride");
                        const divSonuc=document.querySelector("#sonuc");
                    
                        inputTCNO.oninput= function(){
                          
                           if(TCKimlikKOntrol(this.value))
                           {
                            divSonuc.textContent="Tc Kimlik No Geçerli, Teşekkürler.";
                           }
                           else
                           {
                            divSonuc.textContent="Lütfen Geçerli Bir TC Kimlik No Giriniz.";
                           }
                        }
                    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need 2 `querySelector` for both bride and broom, something like:

```js
/*Gelin - TC Kimlik Kontrol*/
var TCKimlikKOntrol = function(deger) {
  deger = deger.toString();
  var basamak = /^[0-9]{11}$/.test(deger);
  var toplamX = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    toplamX += Number(deger.substr(i, 1));
  }
  var kuralX = toplamX % 10 == deger.substr(10, 1);
  var toplamY = 0;
  var toplamY = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
    toplamY += Number(deger.substr(i, 1));
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
    toplamY += Number(deger.substr(i, 1));
  }
  var kuralY = ((toplamY * 7) - toplamY) % 10 == deger.substr(9, 0);
  return basamak && kuralX && kuralY;
};
/*TC Kimlik Kontrol*/

const inputTCNO = document.querySelector("#id_identity_bride");
const inputTCNO2 = document.querySelector("#id_identity_groom");
const divSonuc = document.querySelector("#sonuc");
const divSonuc2 = document.querySelector("#sonuc2");

inputTCNO.oninput = function() {

  if (TCKimlikKOntrol(this.value)) {
    divSonuc.textContent = "Tc Kimlik No Geçerli, Teşekkürler.";
  } else {
    divSonuc.textContent = "Lütfen Geçerli Bir TC Kimlik No Giriniz.";
  }
}

inputTCNO2.oninput = function() {

  if (TCKimlikKOntrol(this.value)) {
    divSonuc2.textContent = "Tc Kimlik No Geçerli, Teşekkürler.";
  } else {
    divSonuc2.textContent = "Lütfen Geçerli Bir TC Kimlik No Giriniz.";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="id_identity_bride">TC Kimlik/Pasaport No:</label>
  <input type="text" name="identity_bride" size="24" class="input" placeholder="Gelin TC Kimlik/Pasaport No" maxlength="11" required id="id_identity_bride">

  <input type="text" name="identity_groom" size="25" class="input" placeholder="Damat TC Kimlik/Pasaport No" maxlength="11" required id="id_identity_groom">
  <div id="sonuc"></div>
  <div id="sonuc2"></div>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is really a simple solution. In addition to this solution, I also found the following solution to avoid conflicts:  jQuery.noConflict(); (function($) { //function })(jQuery);